# RegEx Validation - Invalidate none@anydomain.com but validates other email

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I do have this regex that validates email addresses:
`^\w+(\.\w+)*@(\w+\.)+\w{2,4}$`

What I need is to append this current regex that will invalidate email addresses starting with `none@` OR `na@`

How to? Thanks!

Comment: Note that your regex does not validate all valid email addresses, and rejects many valid addressses. There's more information in the answers to [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/43452)

Comment: You may need to use grouping on the local part (the part before @)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add negative lookahead to the beginning of the pattern:

```
^(?!none@|na@)\w+(\.\w+)*@(\w+\.)+\w{2,4}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/vf4WqT/1

Comment: can u please explain a little what is +\w{2,4} accounting for at the end

Comment: That was in the original pattern, so I'm assuming that's already matching what OP is looking for - a word character after a dot, repeated 2 to 4 times. For example, `bob@bob.com` (repeat 3x) is matched, but `bob@bob.c` (repeat 1x) wouldn't be, nor would `bob@bob.comom` (repeat 5x)

Comment: @Inder It's a bad `tld` validation. Would return false for `mobile` and other new TLDs. (I also dont think a TLD can have an underscore so `[a-z\d]` would be more accurate)